# How to count the element in a column and take the result as a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The DataFrame named `df` is shown as follows.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 3]})
```

`Input:`

```
   id
0   1
1   1
2   3
```

I want to count the number of each `id`, and take the result as a new column `count`.

`Expected:`

```
    id  count
0   1       2
1   1       2
2   3       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign the new `count` column to the dataframe by grouping on `id` and then [transforming](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) that column with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) (or [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.size.html)).

```
>>> f.assign(count=f.groupby('id')['id'].transform('value_counts'))
   id  count
0   1      2
1   1      2
2   3      1
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

My favorite.  `factorize` does not sort and has time complexity of `O(n)`.  For big data sets, `factorize` should be preferred over `np.unique`

```
i, u = df.id.factorize()
df.assign(Count=np.bincount(i)[i])

   id  Count
0   1      2
1   1      2
2   3      1
```

---

### `np.unique` and `np.bincount`

```
u, i = np.unique(df.id, return_inverse=True)
df.assign(Count=np.bincount(i)[i])

   id  Count
0   1      2
1   1      2
2   3      1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df['count'] = df['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts())
#alternative
#from collections import Counter
#df['count'] = df['id'].map(Counter(df['id']))
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['id'].value_counts())
1    2
3    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

Or [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame` with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('id')['id'].transform('size')
print (df)
   id count
0   1     2
1   1     2
2   3     1
```